# PHP cURL missing content after loading a webpage

Tags: php, curl

There is missing content when I try to load a page with cURL using PHP.
Please help.

```
$url = 'https://www.fantasticfiction.com';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Curl only downloads the HTML content. And with your code above it has already downloaded the HTML content and Javascript. Now the missing content is fetched by Javascript/Ajax which is being blocked by the main website's CORS. So, that's why you are seeing  some of the content

Comment: A properly-formulated question should tell what the missing content is, and what would be the expected result. But indeed curl does not process Javascript or Ajax. If you need that consider more complex solutions like Selenium.

Comment: Do you have errors in your browser console?